# Vue js 3 - Property 'projects' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {},

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

[image]

Issue:

```
Property 'projects' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, false, OptionTypesType<{}, ... 4 more ..., {}>, ... 5 more ..., {}>'
```

For some reason it's screaming on computed, You can see my this.project or this.message.

I have no idea how to fix it, please help.
package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.10",
    "less": "^3.0.4",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
```

The issue is coming from when i add to **shims-vue.d.ts**:

```
import { ComponentCustomProperties } from 'vue'
import { Store } from 'vuex'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  // declare your own store states
  interface State {
    count: number
  }

  // provide typings for `this.$store`
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>
  }
}
```

Then it showing my error.
If i remove the store declaration, it's screaming on the store but not on the computed.

Comment: did you export the component with definedComponent? could you share the whole file please?

Comment: I have update my issue.

Comment: if you will remove declare module '@vue/runtime-core', It will work, but then it will scream on the store instead of the computed

Comment: Issue is resolved

Comment: I have added the code to shims-vue.d.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have added

```
import { ComponentCustomProperties } from "vue";
import { Store } from "vuex";

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>;
  }
}
```

to vuex-shim.d.ts and the issue is resolved.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works in vue3 and could be used to create types for any custom property like a custom plugins.

Answer (score 35):

I had a similar issue with Vetur errors on computed properties, and search brought this issue up.

According to this link, this is a known issue regarding Vue's Typings and Typescript.

https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/FAQ.html#property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-combinedvueinstance

Changing computed properties to have an explicit return type seems to fix the problem.

```
greet (): string {
  return this.msg + ' world'
}
```

Some more details and examples:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Annotating-Return-Types

Comment: I have the same problem with Volar in Vue 3, this fix solved the issue.

Answer (score 13):

I lost a lot of time with this error, in my case also related to the ''data'' attributes of vue. First I had some problem with node modules, after uninstalling global, local and reinstalling packages, I noticed that blank projects (created by vue-cli) now worked, only my main project kept reporting this error.

The problem with my project now was that only the components registered globally were not correctly recognized by either vetur or volar, so I kept getting this thread's error only on them.

I ended up discovering a solution by accident, I'll keep it until I find out what's really going on. **Typescript only stops returning this error when I declare "data" like this**:

```
data: () => {
```

Other variations, like this one, don't work

````
    //data() { also not works
    data: function () {
        return {
            comida: 1,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setupVisitsCategoryCard() {
            this.comida = 2 //Property 'comida' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<...'
        }
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me as well. Did you maybe find out what causes the issue?

Comment: I have no idea .

Comment: Ah I fixed it, if you still encounter this issue maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73557254/1636567

Comment: This worked when nothing else helped.  Had a missing property that was a method.  property 'save' does not exist on type vue3instance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using vite, and I fixed it by replacing my typescript config files with the ones in this default vite vuejs-typescript repo:

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/packages/create-vite/template-vue-ts

That repo is a great starting point for Vite+Vue3+Volar+Typescript. Note that you might be getting an error when running the build script, if so you can remove the `vue-tsc --noEmit` build script and `vue-tsc` dependancy, as these didn't work for me on macOS.

**Edit: Especially the `vite-env.d.ts` file seems to do the trick:**

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue';
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>;
  export default component;
}
```