# Vue js 3 with TS - Property 'currentUser' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {},

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

[image: err]

I have similar issues [Vue js 3 - Property 'projects' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {},](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127272/vue-js-3-property-projects-does-not-exist-on-type-createcomponentpublicinst) , but decisions there don't helps. When I tried add :any in currentUser (`currentUser:any () {`) - I have the same error.

```
export default {
    computed: {
      currentUser() {
        return this.$store.state.auth.user
      },
      showAdminBoard() {
        if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser['roles']) {
          return this.currentUser['roles'].includes('ROLE_ADMIN')
        }

        return false
      },
      showModeratorBoard() {
        if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser['roles']) {
          return this.currentUser['roles'].includes('ROLE_MODERATOR')
        }

        return false
      },
    },
    methods: {
      logOut() {
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout')
        this.$router.push('/login')
      },
    },
  }
```

Adding of missed code did not solve the problem
[image: err]

```
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
  export default defineComponent({
    components: { DarkMode },
    computed: {
      currentUser() {
        return this.$store.state.auth.user
      },
      showAdminBoard() {
        if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser['roles']) {
          return this.currentUser['roles'].includes('ROLE_ADMIN')
        }
        return false
      },
      showModeratorBoard() {
        if (this.currentUser && this.currentUser['roles']) {
          return this.currentUser['roles'].includes('ROLE_MODERATOR')
        }
        return false
      },
    },
    methods: {
      logOut() {
        this.$store.dispatch('auth/logout')
        this.$router.push('/login')
      },
    },
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Vue Options API with typescript, you have to use the

```
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
   computed: {},
   ...
})
```

for typings to work

(`defineComponent` is a no-op)
https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#definecomponent

Comment: U are absolutely right about it, I'm really forgot to add this when I change it from <script setup>, but it did not solve the problem