# Cannot read vuex's getter property in computed property

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

do you know how to fix following problem? If I call getter inside computed property, it gives me this error:

> TS2339: Property 'dictionary' does not exist on type
> 'CreateComponentPublicInstance{}, {}, {}, {}, {},
> ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, {}, {}, {}, false, {},
> OptionTypesType{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}>, ... 5 more ..., {}>'.

This is my code:

```
  computed: {
    shuffledDictionary () {
      return _.shuffle(this.dictionary)
    },
    ...mapGetters({
      dictionary: 'learning/dictionary'
    })
  },
```

Used versions:

> "vue": "^3.2.13", "vuex": "^4.1.0",

Comment: How do you create your component?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548935/6225326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @yoduh advice in comment I tried add return type to computed properties and this solves my problem